# How can I use formulas in MC34063 DC-DC converter datasheet?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, datasheet

In MC34063 datasheet, for step up configuration we have this table that describes calculation procedure. I stucked with this recursive formulas in this table. Why they providing such unresolved calculations in the datasheet? They cannot be used as they are in the table, as I thought and saw in another datasheets. Does it mean, that I should resolve equations by myself in order to find ***ton*** and ***toff***?

[image]

Comment: The table is just showing you how to convert frequency and duty cycle to ton and toff

Comment: Saying that ton = (ton-toff)-toff is a fairly useless thing to say!! However, why don't you ask a question that is more specific to your problem. I agree that the formula is somewhat insulting but what you have asked is hardly an EE question.

Comment: Forget the datasheet. Use online calculators instead. [This one](http://www.nomad.ee/micros/mc34063a/) is a good example.

Comment: @RohatKılıç, I have more specific question about this as well. I asked it [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/308926/what-the-difference-between-ipk-and-iout-in-mc33064). And, by the way, I just want to increase my understanding of such things and develop engeneering skills, so I'm trying to verify everything using appropriate datasheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a very unusual looking specification table because it isn't a spec table. You are looking at a table that represents the design calculations in a step by step format.

You start by plugging your known values into the first equation on the right. This gives you the resulting term and value on the left. You then take this new value of the term and plug it into the next or subsequent formula on the left when it is called for. You continue this sequence through the entire table and the result is you know all the required component values and operating parameters.

It is an unusual way of expressing design equations but it is eloquent in its  methodicalness and brevity.

Comment: @GlenW9IQ, That's the point. How can I use the recursive equation? They provided equation to find some value, that already requires to know this value. It just blown my mind, and I don't know what I should do with such step by step table.

Comment: It is not recursive. If you take note of the result of each formula on the right and assign it to the term (variable) on the left, when that term (variable) is needed in a later formula on the left, you simply insert that value.

Comment: Oh... Now I see. I just tried to paste **ton** and **toff** separately, but now I see that we should use full statement like **ton/toff** or **ton + toff**. Always missing such kind of things. Thank you.